# Is it right to close this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is it right to close this question as a duplicate:

- [What's the meaning of life in Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/24231/254)

I can see that its title (i.e. "meaning of life") is similar to some previous titles (i.e. "[What is the meaning and/or purpose of life?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3908/254)"
and
"[Impermanence, nonexistance of self, meaning of life](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7469/254)").

But I think this question's is not a very good title, and that the *content* of this question is different: I think this question is asking, "Why do there seem to be two different goals (e.g. Nirvana, and favourable rebirth)?" -- which isn't the same as what the other questions were asking (and so I think this isn't a duplicate).

Perhaps we could reopen it, possibly change the title somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm you are right, the title and content do mismatch. My assumption with closing the question, was that the OP had generic question about the Goal (what is the goal?), and then used nirvana vs. good rebirth as example of different goals, to support the confusion as the base of the question.

It seemed to me that the confusion was broader than the example. Based on that, I considered the title as more important than the clarification inside the question. In which case we already have several questions on the topic.

If it is the other way around and the title can be ignored, then the question is actually about the two goals and should be reopened.

Comment: I found the title so, I don't know, abstract ... airy-fairy ... that I outright ignored it and looked to the text instead to see what the actual question was. Sometimes I have a question but struggle to summarise it in a title.

Comment: Would "Is the goal of Buddhism nirvana, and/or is it good rebirth?" be an OK title? Or would that still be too generic, confused, broad?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Maybe "why does Buddhism seem to have more than one goal?" or even "Do all Buddhists have the same goal and if not why?"